# Separate keyboard layout for each window in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, input-source, monterey

Is there a way to set up keyboard layouts preferences to have a **separate layout for each window**?

**Use case described step by step:**

- I use **two keyboard layouts**: English and non-English one.
- I often open Terminal, where I use English layout.
- And I often chat in another app using my native language.
- I am tired of switching **global keyboard layout** back and forth.
- I would like **macOS to remember**, which layout was **last-used in each window**.

Especially interesting, if it is possible to do with **native tools** or settings in Monterey rather than 3rd party app. Just like it is possible to do in Linux with a single click in Input methods settings.

PS: there is the [same question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28484/377819), but the **answer is outdated**. There is no such setting anymore. At least **in Monterey**.

Comment: Regarding the outdated answer,  Apple just moved this stuff to system preferences > keyboard > input sources a long time ago.  There should still be a box "automatically switch to a document's input source."  But I don't think it is what you need in your case, is it?

Comment: "automatically switch to a document's source"
Indeed, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPD: better find another solution now due to concerns mentioned in comments.

I have finally found a solution! There is a tool called [Punto Switcher](https://yandex.ru/soft/punto/mac).
It is available for macOS and works almost perfectly for **Russian-English** case.

One needs to install it and grant it permission to operate in **Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Then - turn on a per-application keyboard layout. The bad thing is it is not per-window! Good thing, at least it is per application.

In addition, there is an auto-switch for cases when you forget to switch your layout. And there is a way set exceptions: those applications where auto-switch will not work (you don't want your terminal to auto-switch from English to Russian XD)

PS as recommended [HERE](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253361701?answerId=256302059022#256302059022), I've tried Karabiner, but had no luck. The sought functionality seems to be missing. I've even started a thread at [KE GitHub](https://github.com/pqrs-org/KE-complex_modifications/issues/1025)

Comment: Punto Switcher belongs to yandex
yandex belongs to FSB (KGB)
FSB is intelligent service of nazi russia.
Are you sure that you ready to share your typing with kgb?

Comment: The website seems to be down, and the software no longer available.

Comment: The website is still (again?) operating. But please see the comment above.